# number expected.read Token[2015-02-02 14:19:00] weka project

Tags: data-mining, weka

i hope  you all are doing well!
I have a project at data mining class.Τhe data consists of numerical data and many algorithms do not work.I have to do this:"**you should compare the performance of the following categorization algorithms:
RandomForest, C4.5, JRip, Bayesian Network. Where necessary use them
Weka filters to replace or create values ​​for some properties
new properties. For comparison, adopt the Train / Test Percentage Split type with
percentage for training data equal to 80%.Describe your observations by giving tables with the results and
presenting the performance of the algorithms. Repeat the experiment by putting
percentage for training data equal to 70% and 50% presenting the results.**"
So my first try was to transform the data inside weka with preprocessing data numeric to nominal but a friend of mine suggest that is statistical wrong.So my second try was to use excel to transform all data even the date to numeric,remove the first row(id) and pass it to the weka(I leave double quotes only at date)
.But i have the error that i mention on the title.*The dataset is*:https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Occupancy+Detection+
Thank you for the time.

Answer (score 0):

If you define date-like data as a [DATE attribute](https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/formats_and_processing/arff_stable/) in the ARFF file (using the right format for parsing the strings), then WEKA will treat it as a numeric attribute internally (Java epoch, ie milli-seconds since 1970-01-01).

Instead of using [NumericToNominal](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/NumericToNominal.html), use either the [supervised](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/filters/supervised/attribute/Discretize.html) or [unsupervised](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/Discretize.html) Discretize filter if the algorithm cannot handle numeric attributes.

Converting nominal attributes to numeric ones is not a recommended approach. Instead, try the [supervised](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/filters/supervised/attribute/NominalToBinary.html) or unsupervised [NominalToBinary](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/NominalToBinary.html) filter.